# How to move water to a new dam?

Tags: water-resources, hydroelectric-dams

There are many videos on Youtube about opening of new dams, where the water is already ready to go though the dam.

What I wonder is how engineers moves water to a new dam.

To me it seams as a chicken and egg problem.

- Are explosives involved?
- And how do you prevent the water from hammering into the new dam and destroy it?
- How did they get e.g. the water to Hoover Dam?

Comment: They built the dam on the path of the river. They mined bypass tunnels for use during construction. You'll probably find the answer on a simple YouTube search. Many US dams are now being removed as they are environmentally detrimental and silt up rendering them not much use.

Comment: How do they prevent the water from going into the bypass tunnel while making it? I'd really like to see videos of this. Any idea for search terms? =)

Comment: They let it go along the old river bed while digging the tunnels. "Hoover dam construction", of course.

Comment: There is a film / documentary about the construction of the Hoover dam, includes the info of the treatment of the workers to to the air conditions - take the time to find and then watch it.